# Orthogonal projection from one dimension to another

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image]

I can't see how to do this. I cant see how those two vectors can span a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ when they both have 4 components.

Here's what I've done. I tried to find the column space of these two vectors by putting them into a $4\times2$ matrix

$$
\left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
-4 & 2 & a \\
2 & 2 & b \\
2 & 2 & c \\
-4 & 0 & d
\end{array}\right]
$$

I then row-reduced and got the following results.

$$
\left[\begin{array}{rr|l}
-4 & 2 & a \\
0 & 6 & 2b - a\\
0 & 0 & c - b \\
0 & 0 & 3d - 2a + 2b
\end{array}\right]
$$

So then I used the equation

$3d - 2a + 2b = 0$ to obtain two $1\times3$ vectors that span $\mathbb{R}^3$

$a = b + \frac{3}{2}d$

$\begin{bmatrix}
a \\
b \\
d
\end{bmatrix}
= \operatorname{span}
\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{3}{2} \\
0 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}\right\}$

But I cant project a $4\times1$ onto these vectors because I cant dot a $1\times4$ vector with a $1\times3$ vector.

I have  a feeling I have got the workings of this question all wrong. What am I supposed to be doing?

Comment: It's a typo,   they meant $\Bbb R^4$.

Comment: Stupid typo. What is the correct procedure now, is it getting the projection of v against of each of those vectors and then adding the results together?

Comment: I projected v onto both of those vectors, added the results and got $(14/10, 8/10, 8/10, 4/10)$ but it is showing up as an incorrect answer...

Comment: You need to first use Gram-Schmidt (or something similar) to find a basis for the two-dimensional sub-space that is orthogonal. Then you can project onto each of the basis directions and add.

Comment: Could somebody explain to me what is actually being asked in this question? I think I don't understand what is being asked...

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach. Let $v_1, v_2$ be the given basis for the subspace $V$. Let $p$ be the desired projection. Since $p \in V$, it can be written as $p=[v_1 v_2] x$, where $x \in \mathbb R^2$. The problem then reduces to finding $x$.

Since $p$ is the projection of $v$ on $V$, then $p-v$ must be perpendicular to $V$, or in other words: $<v_i,p-v>=0$, for $i=1,2$. Substituting for $p$ and rewriting slightly gives:
$ v_1^T[v_1 v_2] x = v_1^T v$,
$ v_2^T[v_1 v_2] x = v_2^T v$.

This reduces to two simple equations $40 x_1 = -20$, $12 x_2 = 6$, and so we have $x_1=-\frac{1}{2}, x_2 = \frac{1}{2}$. Using $p=[v_1 v_2] x$, we get $p^T = (3,0,0,2)$.